# geom_density returns plot without considering real values

Tags: r, ggplot2, density-plot

I am trying to plot a density plot for 3 variables over 7 different geographical points, but the output does not show as expected. N should be higher in the middle, but the other seem to plot the same pattern when it is not real, why is this? how could I fix it?

```
Variable1 <- c(rep("E",7), rep("N",7),rep("L",7))
Variable2 <- c(rep(1:7, 3))
value <- c(12.44035, 11.98035333, 11.40821, 12.15833, 13.14826, 11.99339667, 12.17363, 4.073096, 3.946134667, 6.244152, 5.76892, 4.545772, 3.580206667, 2.879470667, 3.6912875, 3.501247, 2.684179, 3.06306, 3.364774, 4.485021333, 3.373649333)
df <- data.frame(Variable1, Variable2, value)

library(ggridges)
ggplot(df, aes(x = Variable2, y = Variable1)) +
  geom_density_ridges(aes(fill = Variable1))
```

[image]

I would like somethinng like this:
[image]

Comment: Do you mean 7 observations, not 7 variables? Also, you've plotted Variable2 on your x-axis, which is the same across each group, instead of the value column. This seems to be a typo where you just plotted the wrong variable

Comment: @camille I mean 7 observaions yes, they are 7 geographical points organised longitudinally. I don't think there is a typo, I want Variable 1 to go on y-axis and Variable 2 to go on x axis. Let me know if its still not clear.

Comment: "The other seem to plot the same pattern when it is not real"—you're plotting the distribution created by `c(rep(1:7, 3))`, i.e. you're plotting 1 through 7 three times. It's the exact same set of numbers, which is why you get the exact same density curve three times. If the column `value` is what you're trying to plot the distribution of, you haven't actually put it in your plotting code anywhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calculating the density of your x-axis, which in your case is `Variable 2`, the same thing (`1,2,...,7`) for every `Variable 1`, so it gives the same density.

So i think that you want your x-axis to be `value`, and you actually don't need `Variable 2` as it's a mere index.

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=value, y=Variable1)) +
  geom_density_ridges(aes(fill=Variable1))
```

[image]

## EDIT 1:

The geom you want actually is `geom_line`, or `geom_smooth` (for prettier graphs), or maybe `geom_area` for filling the area under the curves.

Now, one way of doing it would be putting all the curves on the same y scale:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=Variable2, y=value, color=Variable1)) +
  geom_smooth(fill=NA)
```

[image]

But this doesn't give the separation that you wanted. To do that, the way i know is making a plot for each `Variable1`, and arranging them together (but maybe there's an option with this package `ggridges`, but i never used it). To do that we build a "base" graph:

```
g = ggplot(df, aes(x=Variable2, y=value)) +
  geom_smooth(fill=NA) +
  theme(axis.text.x  = element_blank(),
        axis.title.x = element_blank())
```

Where we removed the x-axis to add only once in the grid. Then, we apply that base for each variable, one at a time, with a for loop:

```
for(i in unique(df$Variable1)){
  df2 = df[df$Variable1==i,]
  assign(i,
         g %+% df2 + ylab(i) +
               ylim(min(df2$value),max(df2$value)))}
```

This creates one graph for each `Variable1`, named as the variable itself. Now we add the x-axis in the last plot and arrange them together:

```
N = N + theme(axis.text.x  = element_text(),
              axis.title.x = element_text())

gridExtra::grid.arrange(E,L,N, nrow=3)
```

Output:

[image]

## EDIT 2:

To use colors, first we don't pass the `geom` to `g`:

```
g = ggplot(df, aes(x=Variable2, y=value)) +
  theme(axis.text.x  = element_blank(),
        axis.title.x = element_blank())
```

Then we create a vector of colors that we'll use in the loop:

```
color = c("red", "green", "blue")
names(color) = unique(df$Variable1)
```

Then we pass the `color` argument inside the `geom` that we omitted earlier.

But first, let me talk about the available geoms: We could use a smooth geom area, which will give something like this:

[image]

Which is good but has a lot of useless area under the graphs. To change that, we can use `geom_ribbon`, where we can use the argument `aes(ymin=min(value)-0.1, ymax=value)` and `ylim(min(df2$value)-0.1, max(df2$value))` to stop the graph at the minimal value (minus 0.1). The problem is that the smoothing function of ggplot doesn't work well with geom_ribbon, so we only have the option of a "rough" graph:

[image]

Code for the smoot area:

```
for(i in unique(df$Variable1)){
  df2 = df[df$Variable1==i,]
  assign(i,
         g %+% df2 + ylab(i) +
         stat_smooth(geom="area", fill=color[i]))}
```

Code for the rough ribbon:

```
for(i in unique(df$Variable1)){
  df2 = df[df$Variable1==i,]
  assign(i,
         g %+% df2 + ylab(i) + ylim(min(df2$value)-0.1,max(df2$value)) +
         geom_ribbon(aes(ymax=value, ymin=min(value)-0.1), fill=color[i]))}
```

I searched for a way to work aroud that smotthing problem but foud nothing, i'll create a question in the site and if i find a solution i'll show it here!

## EDIT 3:

After asking in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64578056/bad-interaction-between-stat-smooth-and-geom-ribbon), i found that using `after_stat` inside the `aes` argument of `stat_smooth(geom="ribbon", aes(...))` solves it (more info read the link).

```
for(i in unique(df$Variable1)){
  df2 = df[df$Variable1==i,]
  assign(i,
         g %+% df2 + ylab(i) + 
           stat_smooth(geom="ribbon", fill=color[i],
                       aes(ymax=after_stat(value), ymin=after_stat(min(value))-0.1)))}
```

[image]

Comment: It would be something close to this. Showing on the x axis the Variable2 1:7, where on the y axis the Variable 1 E, N, L show the "values" across the Variable 2. Does this make sense? I wonder if the right way of plotting the data I'd like to do. See edited post with the desired output

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't. You are plotting a density, you can think about it (without precision) like a smooth histogram, which is (again without precision) "how many times does this x-value appear on my data?", so the x-axis with `Variable 2` will always give your current graph, as you'll be asking "how many times does 1/2/.../7 appear on my data". The point is that you don't want a density plot. But I understood what you want, so I'll search what `geom` does what you want and i'll edit my post :)

Comment: Ah, thanks! I was wondering if I was choosing the rght plot to do so, maybe some kind of stacked plot? I'll wait for your edit :)

Comment: Check if it helped!

Comment: This is super helpful, I can work on theme_ and axis later, but yes, geom_area would work better to fill the area under the geom_smooth? Could you help me here, sorry I am learning R still!

Comment: This is super, I will have a read and apply it to my data :) Thanks again!!!

Comment: It was easier then i thought! check the (last, hopefully) edit