# bad interaction between stat_smooth and geom_ribbon

Tags: r, ggplot2

I was answering [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64574595/geom-density-returns-plot-without-considering-real-values), which required plotting smooth areas, but removing 'useless' area. To do that on a simple `geom_area` (not smooth), i'd just use `geom_ribbon` with `aes(ymax=y, ymin=min(y))`. But turning a `stat_smooth(geom="area")` into a `stat_smooth(geom="ribbon", aes(ymax=y, ymin=min(y)))` does not yield the expected result.

`geom_area` to `geom_ribbon` (dummy data at the end):

`ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y)) + geom_area()` to `ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y)) + geom_ribbon(aes(ymax=y, ymin=min(y)))`

[image]

Now the smooth version:

`ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y)) + stat_smooth(geom="area")` to `ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y)) + stat_smooth(geom="ribbon", aes(ymax=y, ymin=min(y)))`

[image]

The output that i wanted is something like this:

[image]

I found some solutions that involved making a new data frame with "smoothed data", and then plotting that normally with a `geom_ribbon`, but that applied only when you had a known function and could easily generate more observations. Another try was to set the y limits to `ylim(min(y), max(y))`, but ggplot doesn't plot any geom that is "caught" in a limit, so maybe if there's a way to change that feature it'd be a way to solve my problem.

Dummy data:

```
df <- data.frame(
  x = 1:7,
  y = c(12.44, 11.98, 11.40, 12.15, 13.14, 11.99, 12.17))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean something like this? If you want to use a calculated variable in your mapping, you need to wrap it with `after_stat()`. `after_stat(y)` means "use the `y` value calculated by the stat, not the `y` value in the original data frame."

```
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame(
  x = 1:7,
  y = c(12.44, 11.98, 11.40, 12.15, 13.14, 11.99, 12.17)
)

ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y)) + 
  geom_point() +
  stat_smooth(
    geom="ribbon", 
    aes(ymax = after_stat(y), ymin = after_stat(min(y))),
    fill = "skyblue"
  )
#> `geom_smooth()` using method = 'loess' and formula 'y ~ x'
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-10-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Yes! `after_stat` sets the limits to the plot after using the "normal" values on the smooth calculation, is that it?

Comment: `after_stat(y)` means "use the `y` value calculated by the stat, not the `y` value in the original data frame."